# Link error relating to _CGImageSourceCreateWithData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I get an error while compiling.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
"_CGImageSourceCreateWithData", referenced from:
  ___-[AVCamCaptureManager captureStillImage]_block_invoke_1 in AVCamCaptureManager.o
"_CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex", referenced from:
  ___-[AVCamCaptureManager captureStillImage]_block_invoke_1 in AVCamCaptureManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks like a missing library but I included the ones i think i needed such as

CoreGraphics,
QuartzCore
Foundation.framework

I also added in headers

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import <ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h>
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

I've been chasing my tail for 40mins, what am I missing guys?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: clean the targets and then run it

Comment: I see you've imported many headers - that's fine. Have all the corresponding frameworks been added to the project, such as AVFoundation.framework?

Comment: @Luke AVFoundation is in the project. @ Tendulkar cleaning made no difference. Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Answer (score 18):

for CGImageSourceCreateWithData

Add ImageIO.framework,

but by the looks of your #import directives I would say you also need to add at least:
AVFoundation and MobileCoreServices

Comment: doesn't help. I imported all of those, still get error for armv7 architecture.

Comment: Yes, sorry but i dont remember how. I think it was "Link Binary With Libraries" in Xcode Build Phases. And if you have more than one target in your Xcode project, you need to check that for all targets.

Comment: This should be the answer. I added ImageIO.framework and the linker error vanished.

Comment: This is the answer and make sure you target valid architectures only.

Comment: Solved my issuess